# HTTPS with NSURLConnection - NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ssl, https, certificate

I have an application that connects fine over http.  When trying https I got the error that says that the root cert is not trusted.  I found URLs for my site certificate, its CA certificate, and the CA's root certificate and have added them through Safari to the phone.  Now when I go to Preferences -> General -> Profiles I can see all my certificates that go all the way up the chain.  There is a red unsigned label on each certificate.  Still when I connect I get the NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted error.  I'm trying to figure where to go next.

Any help would be great.  The only other thing that may affect this, is that I am connecting to an odd port.  So my url is www.domain.com:port. Does the port number create a certificate - domain name mismatch?

Now I have used the iPhone Configuration Utility to add a configuration profile to the phone.  It has my root certificate, ca certificate, and site certificate.  The profile on the phone says its verified.  In the details I can see my three certificates.  But when I try to connect, I still get the untrusted certificate error.  Any suggestions?

Just trying to see if anyone else can help on this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a supported API for ignoring bad certificates during NSURLConnection loads. To do so, simply add something like this to your NSURLConnection delegate:

```
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
  return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
  if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    if (... user allows connection despite bad certificate ...)
      [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

  [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

Note that connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge: can send its message to challenge.sender (much) later, after presenting a dialog box to the user if necessary, etc.

Comment: How do you know what dialog box to present? Seems like you could get here reasons other than NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted (such as NSURLErrorServerCertificateHasBadDate, which I assume means it's expired).

Comment: can we use above methods for ultra cassini? Right now i am using IIS and used above methods for untrusted certificate but for some special case i have to consider ultra cassini also.