# How to exchange data with an webserver the secure way?

Tags: security, ios

I have an web application running on a server. It has an API which I can access with https://mywebservice.org/private/secretStatistics.xml?token=X59FG43VPT

When the token is correct (like a password), then I get back an XML. I import it with NSXMLParser to Core Data.

I thought about using NSURLConnection to download that XML. Is this my best bet on iOS? How hard is it to download from an https secured source?

And can I add additional authentification credentials? On the server side, I can easily set up that the server asks for username and password before returning the XML.

Which classes would I use to SEND data to a server? Also NSURLConnection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes HTTPS is the best choice.  and Yes [NSURLConnection supports https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578121/https-with-nsurlconnection-nsurlerrorservercertificateuntrusted).