# Https data in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hello friends
i am using https server data using JSOn webservice but i don't know what the problem of certificate.
i had already work with http data but am not work with secure https data..
can any one help me???

Comment: Can you access the service using HTTPS from a desktop browser? Does it show any security warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just deal with fetching data from a `HTTPS` connection, just use the `NSURLConnection`. They also handle `HTTPS` traffic.

Have a look at this question for certificate handling: [HTTPS with NSURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578121/https-with-nsurlconnection-nsurlerrorservercertificateuntrusted)

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library for dealing with HTTP requests in iOS apps. I use it for all of our apps.

Are you using a self-signed certificate? If so, you'll need to set the 'validatesSecureCertificate' to NO or the request will fail.

Here's some code for doing a post on HTTPS

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:@"https://example.com/post"];
[request setPostValue:email forKey:@"email"];
[request setPostValue:name forKey:@"name"];

// IMPORTANT: allows our self-signed cert to be ok
request.validatesSecureCertificate = NO;

[request startSyncronous];

 NSLog(@"post returned a %d", [request responseStatusCode] );

 NSError *error = [request error];
 if (!error) {
   NSString *response = [request responseString];
   NSLog(@"SUCCESS! Response is %@", response);
 } else {
  NSLog(@"FAIL!! %@", [error description] );
 }
```

If you'd rather use the built-in Apple stuff, then Erik Aigner's answer  explains how to deal with this using NSURLConnection.

Before you start coding I'd recommend using a CURL command to test the connection from your dev machine e.g. for the example above:

```
 curl -i -L -k -X POST "https://example.com/test" -d "email=foo@example.com&name=bar"
```

If this doesn't work, then the code above won't work either.

Comment: thnx for your response. but i want to use get method not post method and m never work with https:// webservice data. can you give me any related example link..