# iOS HTTPS possible communication problem

Tags: iphone, https

My server certificate expired a couple of days ago and my app (which communicates with the server over HTTPS) crashes now (unable to connect). It is a simple synchronous post https call. The program is never run on the server. The access is never logged in the Apache log. This leads me to believe that the expired certificate is the problem. Nothing in the code on the server or the app has changed in 3 weeks.

Is there a way to set a flag that says that the certificate doesn't have to valid in order to make the connection?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a non-private API manner if you're using ASIHTTPRequest.

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"];
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url]

[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
```

Or see this answer (using NSURLConnection delegate)

[HTTPS with NSURLConnection - NSURLErrorServerCertificateUntrusted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578121/https-with-nsurlconnection-nsurlerrorservercertificateuntrusted)

Comment: Is that a third-party package?

Comment: Looks interesting. Would require a fair amount to change my app. Is there a way to do this with NSURLConnection also?