# NSJSONSerialization crashes when pulling data from specific url

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, json, nsjsonserialization

I'm trying to pull data from this url, but I am running into some problems. Why does this crash on the `NSJSONSerialization` line? Is there a better way to download info from this website?

EDIT: I changed jsonArray from a NSArray to a NSDictionary, but it still crashes in the same spot. Is there a different way to download this data?

```
NSString *url=@"https://api.p04.simcity.com/simcity/rest/users/search/J3d1.json";

NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

NSURLResponse *resp = nil;
NSError *err = nil;

NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: theRequest returningResponse: &resp error: &err];

NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: response options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

NSLog(@"%@",jsonArray);
```

For reference, the JSON is:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "uri": "/rest/user/20624",
            "tutorialState": 0,
            "nucleusId": 20624,
            "id": 20624,
            "screenName": "R3DEYEJ3D1",
            "lastLogin": 1362666027000,
            "isOnline": "true",
            "avatarImage": "https://api.p04.simcity.com/simcity/rest/user/20624/avatar",
            "cities_count": 0,
            "canChat": "true"
        },
        {
            "uri": "/rest/user/46326",
            "tutorialState": 0,
            "nucleusId": 46326,
            "id": 46326,
            "screenName": "J3D1_WARR10R",
            "lastLogin": 1363336534000,
            "isOnline": "false",
            "avatarImage": "https://api.p04.simcity.com/simcity/rest/user/46326/avatar",
            "cities_count": 0,
            "canChat": "true"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You don't get an array as response. you already get a dictionary.

Comment: Could mark where it crashes, and maybe the error message.

Comment: it seems to parse it fine. whats the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server is presenting a certificate that isn't trusted by the OS - I had to use the `-k` flag to `curl` your JSON so should have thought of this earlier.

In order to get around this, you'll need to switch to using an asynchronous `NSURLConnection` and implement its delegate methods. See this answer from [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578121/https-with-nsurlconnection-nsurlerrorservercertificateuntrusted) to implement a working solution to your parsing issue. I implemented it inside the app delegate, but you can for example put this in an asynchronous `NSOperation` and use it there.

**WARNING: This code will connect to any server, regardless of trust. This is asking for a man in the middle attack. Do not send sensitive information to a server when this type of trust is enabled**. You MUST implement code to verify your server's identity, and replace the `if (YES)` in `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge` with a test against the result of that check.

My current understanding is that this should be done by including your certificate's public key in the app bundle as a DER file, and using `SecCertificateCreateWithData` to create a `SecCertficiateRef` that will be used as the input to `SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates`. Then, `SecTrustEvaluate` should be used to verify the identity. I base this understanding on my reading of the [Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html) and sample code found in [this blog post](http://blog.wingsofhermes.org/?p=58) on how to trust your own certificate.

```
@interface AppDelegate () <NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>

//  This is needed to collect the response as it comes back from the server
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *mutableResponseData;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Xcode template code for setting up window, ignore...
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    //  Instantiate our connection 
    NSString *urlString = @"https://api.p04.simcity.com/simcity/rest/users/search/J3d1.json";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    if(![NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self]) {
        NSLog(@"Handle an error case here.");
    }

    return YES;
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    //  Prepare to recevie data from the connection
    NSLog(@"did receive response: %@", response);
    self.mutableResponseData = [NSMutableData data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //  Handle an error case here
    NSLog(@"did fail with error: %@", error);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    //  Build up the response data
    [self.mutableResponseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    id JSONObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.mutableResponseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    if (!JSONObject) {
        //  Handle error here
        NSLog(@"error with JSON object");
    }
    else if ([JSONObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        //we're in business
        NSDictionary *dict = JSONObject;
        NSLog(@"dict is %@", dict);
    }
    else {
        //  Handle case of other root JSON object class...
    }
}


//  The following two methods allow any credential to be used. THIS IS VULNERABLE TO MAN IN THE MIDDLE ATTACK IN ITS CURRENT FORM
- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust]) {
        // WE ARE POTENTIALLY TRUSTING ANY CERTIFICATE HERE. Replace YES with verification of YOUR server's identity to avoid man in the middle attack.
        //  FOR ALL THAT'S GOOD DON'T SHIP THIS CODE
#warning Seriously, don't ship this.
        if (YES) {
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
    }

    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];   
}

@end
```

Comment: Did this, still crashes on the same line

Comment: Please go in further detail on how to do this as this sounds like it could be the problem.

Comment: @user1413558 I'm trying to figure that out now, I get no response data, no NSURLResponse, and no error either so this will be fun to figure out :)

Comment: @user1413558 I just updated my answer with an implementation that parses correctly. Please read my comments carefully, as this trusts any server's certificate.

Answer (score 0):

NSJSONSerialization will always crash if the data  is nil. You need to put a conditional in to see if that URL contains any data.

Comment: No it won't. It will set the error object and return `nil`: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @MikeD Try it - passing `nil` crashes with an invalid argument exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try put the url in the browser to make sure that gives you a valid JSON, also make sure the parsed data is Array or NSDictionary